# NSTextAlignmentCenter is not working with UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

Tags: ios, uitableview

When cell style is default, `NSTextAlignment` worked, but when i changed it to subtitle, it does not work.

```
cell.textLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the `NSTextAlignment` of your cell's subtitle label. The reason is that this label is only as wide as the text. If you don't believe me, you can try to set it's background color:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
}
```

So, you can see, that your `UILabel` changes its width according to the text in it.

Official documents are also against its alignment:

> A style for a cell with a **left-aligned** label across the top and a
>   **left-aligned** label below it in smaller gray text. The iPod application
>   uses cells in this style.

So, I can suggest **three** different ways to achieve your goal:

**First way**

You can create your own custom cell following these tutorials:

- [appcoda.com](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)
- [codigator.com](http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-uitableview-tutorial-custom-cell-and-delegates/)

You can add both the title label and subtitle by yourself and setup all of their properties.

**Second way**

Here is another workaround, you can use it if you don't want to implement custom cells. Just use the following method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UILabel *myLabel;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yourX, yourY, yourWidth, yourHeight)];
        myLabel.tag = 1;
        myLabel.textAlignment= UITextAlignmentCenter;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel];
    }

    myLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    //Add text to it
    myLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

**Third way**

You can implement method, which will change your cell's subtitle label's text alignment after rendering. That's definitely not the best solution, but you can try it if you want:

```
- (void) updateCenteringForTextLabelInCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell 
{
    UILabel *myLabel = cell.textLabel;
    myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(myLabel.frame.origin.x, myLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, myLabel.frame.size.height);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //use your already implemented code
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateCenteringForTextLabelInCell:) withObject:cell afterDelay:0.05];
}
```

**Summary:**

I'd recommend you to use the first way, because all others are a little tricky. Besides it, you can add a lot of different elements to your custom cell later, and that can be very useful.

Comment: vote up requires reputations. i don't have any yet :(